# Failed to instantiate module starter due to: TypeError: $stateProvider.state is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I am trying to run the app on the server and I am getting this as an error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
TypeError: $stateProvider.state is not a function
```

My app.js is

```
angular.module('starter', ['ngRoute','ui.router', 'ngAnimate','controllers', 'services'])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('college', {
    url: '/college',
    templateUrl: 'html/colleges.html',
    controller: 'collegeCtrl'
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/college');
 }]);
```

My index.html page goes like the following

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <!--Import materialize.css-->
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
 <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <!--controllers -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/collegeCtrl.js"></script>
 <!--Services -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="services/httprequestService.js">
 </script>
 <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<div class="content">
<div ui-view ng-class="transition">
  default content
 </div>
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

colleges.js

```
 angular.
 module('controllers',[]).
 controller('collegeCtrl', function ($scope,$state) {

 });
```

I really don't understand what is going wrong. I have googled the error for the solution but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="starter">
```

Comment: Works like a charm. What was the mistake I was doing. I have added ng-app to the body section. What difference does it make?

Comment: There may be angular version issue because its should work in body tag as well.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) { 
 ...
}
```

Whatever you inject should be in the same order or else it can be a *dependency injection mismatch* sort of problem

Comment: You need to do `npm install angular-ui-router` before injection.. take a look at this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/legacy

Comment: I did that and even included the path of angular-ui-router.js in index.html also

Comment: You need to add `angular.js` first and then your `angular-ui-router.js` in `index.html` file..

Comment: It is in the same order as you specified.

Comment: Can i know why are you injecting these into your module `'controllers', 'services'`?

Comment: I am taking all controllers into single module "controllers" and all services into single module "services". Please check the update.